# Localização "geográfica" de dispositivos em ambientes internos

Tags: geolocalização, mobile

Em ambientes externos a localização geográfica, efetuada por meio de GPS ou triangularização com antenas de celular, já é praticamente um "problema resolvido", contando até com recursos e facilidades disponíveis na API dos principais sistemas operacionais para dispositivos móveis, como Android e iOS.

Mas como é feita a localização "geográfica" (entre aspas aqui porque não é bem uma localização no globo) de dispositivos móveis em ambientes internos, tal como um grande salão de festas? Já existe alguma solução padronizada ou de fácil reuso para isso?

P.S.: Em alguns comentários foram indicadas ferramentas comerciais que fazem isso (e essa informação com certeza foi muito bem-vinda!), mas eu desejaria ter uma resposta detalhando o funcionamento de uma (ou mais!) dessas soluções porque eu acredito que isso seria útil também para toda a comunidade do SOPT.

Comment: Pergunta interessante. A única solução que conheço para isso (proprietária e para um fim bem específico) depende da instalação de vários sensores no ambiente que se quer monitorar. Mas se você tiver vários dispositivos móveis em uma rede wireless, *deve* ser possível fazer algum tipo de triangulação e detectar sua posição em relação ao roteador.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sensores de que tipo? Se você puder fornecer uma resposta dando algumas dicas de como essa solução proprietária funciona (claro, se puder divulgar as informações), seguramente vai ser útil. :)

Comment: De uma pesquisada por "indoor positioning", pelo que pesquisei existem algumas soluções proprietárias (usando WiFi). Achei esses dois desenvolvedores: http://www.wifarer.com/ e http://www.meridianapps.com/. Olhando rápido, não sei se eles oferecem a acurácia que precisa, mas chegam perto.

Comment: Eu não sei quais são os "sensores", e na verdade acho que não são sensores, e sim pequenos radiotransmissores. Cada um é instalado numa posição previamente conhecida, e o dispositivo móvel se orienta de acordo com eles. Elas soluções via WiFi que o Wakim linkou parecem mais simples, e valem uma tentativa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu estou elaborando uma solução dessas para a universidade onde trabalho.

Ela segue a linha do comentário do @bfavaretto, com tags NFC para facilitar a localização individual (um indivíduo pode se 'assinar' em um determinado ambiente), mas para localização espacial a solução se baseia na *Google Maps Geolocation API*.

Tradução livre do [post a respeito no Techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/17/google-apis-for-location-tracking-gps-free-geolocation/):

> A API de Geolocalização do Google Maps [...] tenta triangular a sua
>   posição, observando para as torres de celular e pontos de acesso Wi-Fi
>   ao seu redor. [...] Segundo o Google, este serviço destina-se a [...]
>   permitir uma melhor localização no interior (onde o GPS não funciona).

A API se calibra ao longo do tempo, cruzando a informação dos seus mapas internos (que criam bordas, ou *boundaries* na terminologia da API) com análise estatística dos dados capturados em cada requisição (lista de conexões WiFi, antenas de serviço móvel [mesmo que você não esteja conectado a elas] próximas e eventual GPS, junto com a qualidade de sinal). Ou seja, em teoria ela fica mais precisa com o passar do tempo.

Para visualização, você pode utilizar o *Google Indoor Maps*, que inclusive permite fotografias internas de alta resolução via *Street View*:
https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/

Mais a respeito da tecnologia neste artigo (em inglês):
http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-frontier-for-google-maps-mapping.html

Bônus: As 5 mais utilizadas tecnologias de geolocalização indoor (em inglês):
http://www.thoughtden.co.uk/blog/2012/04/top-5-indoor-geolocation-technologies/

Comment: Muito boa resposta! :)