# É possível fazer orientação espacial somente com sensor magnético?

Tags: android

É possível determinar a orientação espacial do *smartphone* usando somente os valores `x`, `y`, e `z` do sensor magnético?

Comment: Cara talvez, caso você consigo criar um grande plano cartesiano ao seu redor, isso algoritmicamente falando, o indicado é o GPS mesmo, mais simples, só pegar sua posição em coordenadas geográficas no planeta longitude e latitude e pronto.

Comment: Você poderia fornecer mais detalhes de qual seria o uso destes valores na sua aplicação? O que você quer fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, os valores `x`, `y` e `z` que você se refere, não são do sensor magnético, mas sim de um componente chamado [acelerômetro](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/curiosidade/2652-o-que-e-um-acelerometro-.htm). O sensor magnético que você se referiu é um [Sensor de Efeito Hall](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_de_efeito_Hall), que mede a presença e a intensidade de um campo magnético, e por consequência, pode medir o magnetismo do norte magnético (sul geográfico). Existem acelerômetros que trabalham utilizando Sensores de Efeito Hall, mas não entrarei nesses detalhes.

Grosseiramente falando, acelerômetro é um componente eletrônico capaz de medir a aceleração em um ou mais eixos a partir das forças que estejam atuando sobre ele. Cabe dizer que essa aceleração é medida em relação a força da gravidade e, portanto, a aceleração é medida em g, podendo ser facilmente convertida para m/s².

Então suponha que temos um **VANT** (Veículo Aéreo Não Tripulado), que esteja decolando do repouso, de uma bela pista em um aeroclube em algum lugar do Brasil:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo Aguiar, a aceleração real de deslocamento desta aeronave é medida pela fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que Ax(v) é a aceleração resultante do eixo em que você pretende medir e A(v) é a aceleração total recebida. Já o g(Φ) é devido a incidência da força da gravidade, devido ao ângulo de inclinação Φ, já que a força da gravidade também atua sobre o acelerômetro.

Aguiar afirma que para se fazer o equacionamento da aceleração resultante sobre
a aeronave, é necessário obter-se o ângulo de inclinação (tilt) feita pela inclinação de arfagem (pitch), para que a aceleração seja calculada.

[Uma outra coisa muito interessante](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrancada) que você deve lembrar das aulas de física do ensino médio, é que é possível medir velocidade e posição a partir da aceleração, já que a derivada da aceleração em função ao tempo é a velocidade, e se você derivar de novo, terás a posição em metros a partir da origem.

Respondendo a sua pergunta: Sim! É possível, mas fazer isso a partir de um acelerômetro é algo bem mais complexo, pois você vai precisar monitorar o tempo e terás que derivar para obter a posição, além de que você vai precisar utilizar um conjunto de outros tipos de sensores e sua aplicação não será precisa. Recomendo que você utilize GPS, pois além de ser mais fácil de se trabalhar, você terá uma posição bastante precisa do usuário, em uma escala global. A possibilidade de detectar a posição de determinado usuário, pode trazer aplicações bem interessantes, uma delas é o conceito de Jogos Móveis Locativos, demonstrado [neste artigo](http://www.pabloroxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Artigo.pdf) do meu amigo Pablo Roxo. Se você fornecer mais detalhes da sua aplicação, talvez eu possa ajudá-lo a escolher quais são os melhores sensores para o que pretendes fazer. Em breve estarei acrescentando mais detalhes a minha resposta, falarei sobre outros sensores que podem te ajudar a monitorar a posição.

Comment: Essa resposta é apenas um esboço, irei respondê-la de uma forma mais detalhada assim que for possível.

Comment: Não está claro na pergunta, mas talvez a sugestão do GPS não seja muito útil ao usuário porque ele pode estar interessado na [localização do dispositivo em ambientes internos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26726/localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-geogr%C3%A1fica-de-dispositivos-em-ambientes-internos). Assim, acho melhor você cobrar um exclarecimento dele antes de gastar muito seu tempo melhorando a pergunta nesse sentido. :)

Comment: @Avelino, não sei se é isso que a usuário quer com a pergunta, mas seu "esboço" de resposta está bem interessante, li inteirinha, viajei em 90% dela, mas me senti mas inteligente nesse momento (que estou escrevendo) após lê-la. Só uma sugestão para quando for melhora-la, quando citar algum autor, por favor link o artigo original (se estiver disponível virtualmente né (Ainda se usa livros? hehe)) pois fiquei curioso para conhecer "Aguiar", e seu artigo ou livro sobre o assunto. Hehe. De qualquer forma já ganha o meu +1, para animar a aperfeiçoa-la.